# Draw an Item like home screen icon of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to draw an Item that similar as item of iPhone. I have also draw with UIView like this[image]

But the item I want like this :
[image]

How can I draw like round buttton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the corner Radius of your view and insert the label below it.

iPhone supports the cornerRadius property on the CALayer class. Every view has a CALayer instance that you can manipulate.

First of all `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and link to the `QuartzCore framework` to get access to CALayer's headers and properties.Then,

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Comment: How do we do for setting the corner radius ? Could you give me an example if you have free time? Thanks in Advances.

Comment: I have added the code. Its just one line of code and you need to include a framework for using it

Answer (score 2):

USE THIS CODE

```
  UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
  [bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  // Get the Layer of any view
  CALayer * l = [bt layer];
  [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [l setCornerRadius:10.0];

  // You can even add a border
  [l setBorderWidth:4.0];
  [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
  [self.view addSubview:bt];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make round edges by

```
 yourview.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0; // or other value
```